# install Thick client on idempiere

Tags: authentication, server, connection, thick-client, idempiere

During installation, when I click on ADempiere-client.exe file to run it for login, I couldn't. because the bellow massage will occur,"in dialog box"

**java hotspot(tm) 64-bit server vm - 1.8.0_131 <> 1.6.0 | 1.7.0**

Answer (score 0):

Specified your question.. Do you run from from Eclipse? But the problem i can see your java not supported for idempiere you using. Use idempiere new version 5.1..

Learn to make your workspace in here :

[This link for setup your workspace for idempiere](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Developing_Plug-Ins_-_Setup_the_workspace)

Answer (score 0):

The dialog box said you need to use java version 1.6.x or 1.7.x. but you have 1.8.

What idempiere version ? on idempeire 4.1 swing client you need java 8